# Webserver behind NAT router not reachable

Tags: networking, router, nat, tcp, wireshark

I have a mysterious problem with a little server that I'm running at home, behind a NAT router. I'm running several web and other services there, which I can also access from outside my LAN through port forwarding. Since a few days, I cannot access the web server anymore (neither per port 80 nor 443). But only from *outside* the LAN! From within, I still can access without trouble. SSH still works from outside, though on a non-standard port.

So I did a Wireshark trace where a browser outside the LAN tries to access the server. For readability and anonymity I changed the server IP address to s.s.s.s and the browser IP address to b.b.b.b.

```
No.  Time      Source    Destination  Protocol Length Info
1    0.000000  b.b.b.b   s.s.s.s      TCP      66     59468 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
2    0.022883  s.s.s.s   b.b.b.b      TCP      66     80 → 59468 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1380 SACK_PERM=1 WS=128
3    0.022949  b.b.b.b   s.s.s.s      TCP      54     59468 → 80 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=66048 Len=0
4    0.025405  b.b.b.b   s.s.s.s      HTTP     294    GET / HTTP/1.0 
5    0.026677  s.s.s.s   b.b.b.b      HTTP     666    HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden  (text/html)
6    0.026678  s.s.s.s   b.b.b.b      TCP      54     80 → 59468 [FIN, ACK] Seq=613 Ack=241 Win=0 Len=0
7    0.026678  s.s.s.s   b.b.b.b      TCP      54     80 → 59468 [RST, ACK] Seq=614 Ack=241 Win=0 Len=0
```

The TCP connection is set up properly. Then the browser sends the HTTP GET request and receives a "403 Forbidden" response. Also, almost *simultaneously* with the HTTP response message it gets a FIN and a RST message!

On the server side I did a tcpdump of the same communication:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -n port 80 or port 443
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
16:53:26.625013 IP b.b.b.b.59468 > s.s.s.s.80: Flags [S], seq 2382139585, win 8192, options [mss 1380,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
16:53:26.625131 IP s.s.s.s.80 > b.b.b.b.59468: Flags [S.], seq 1966829679, ack 2382139586, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:53:26.647631 IP b.b.b.b.59468 > s.s.s.s.80: Flags [.], ack 1, win 258, length 0
16:53:26.650205 IP b.b.b.b.59468 > s.s.s.s.80: Flags [R.], seq 1, ack 1, win 258, length 0
```

Here, the TCP connection setup (first three packets) is still ok. **But where the heck are the HTTP messages?** There's neither request nor response?! What's going on? And why is the server immediately closing the connection with a RST packet?

At first I suspected some misconfiguration of Apache (I'm sometimes changing things there without really knowing what I'm doing). So I turned Apache off and started a Python SimpleHTTPServer script. The Wireshark and tcpdump traces turned out pretty much the same, but now at least a got some error output from the Python script:

```
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('b.b.b.b', 59468)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 655, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 340, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 310, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 476, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
----------------------------------------
```

But that didn't really bring me any further. Does anyone have an idea of what could be the reason for all this?

Comment: Does the web server have a static IP, reserved within DHCP or auto-configured (its address could change)?

Comment: I don't think your client and server capture shows the same connection. The SYN has a different MSS and Window Scaling factor.

Comment: Can you run a fresh capture on server and client and email me the pcap files? odin(dot)systemgenerated(at)gmail.com

Comment: The web server has a static IP, though all other addresses in that LAN are dynamic.

Comment: About the MSS and window size - I'm not sure, but I suppose a NAT can change that? I did mail you the pcap files, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: What are you using to generate the HTTP requests? Chrome, Firefox, wget, curl, telnet, nc, etc

Comment: If the server works fine locally, but not over the internet try changing to a non-standard port and also try with https on standard and non-standard ports. It's possible whoever controls the network you're using (ISP) has made a change that is breaking things.

Comment: In addition, double-check you're using the correct IP to connect from outside the LAN. If you're using a hostname, try using an IP instead and check the router to see what IP it's getting versus using an online service or another method for obtaining the IP.

Comment: I use Lynx (don't laugh!) to connect to the server. I find full-scale browsers not practical for testing server settings because I never know what they remember about a page.

Comment: @nijave: I use a (dyn-DNS) host name. But this is really interesting! **If I use the IP address instead, it works!** How is this possible?! What's the difference? And thanks a lot for the hint!

Comment: You will need to do an nslookup to see what the domain name is resolving to. Domain names have something called a TTL (time to live) which specifies how long a DNS server should consider them valid before checking with the source (DynDNS) in this case. It's possible your equipment didn't update the domain name or the old IP address is still cached with whatever DNS server the client having issues is using.

Comment: It's also possible the domain name was correct, but you could still have an issue with your Apache configuration. IP address likely uses the default or first found information. If you have the DynDNS name specified inside a VirtualHost as "Server Name" then that block will take effect. The other possibility was someone else is using your old IP address that's also running an Apache server that's returning a 403.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for sending over the capture files.

There is a firewall or some kind of middlebox (possibly Cisco ASA) between your client and server which is intercepting your web traffic and generating the 403 message and RST packets. Here's why:

1. The TCP three way handshake completes successfully between the client and server. Round trip time is approximately **30ms**. All good so far.
2. The client sends an HTTP GET request to the server.
3. A 403 Forbidden message is sent back to the client **2ms** after the request is sent which is *far* too quick to have been from the actual server. The traffic capture from the server also shows no sign of the HTTP request. **Some device between the two devices has generated this 403**.

   Note the verbage of the 403:

   > You are attempting to access a forbidden site.
   >   Consult your system administrator for details

   That is not a standard Apache 403 and from a quick Google, I can see reference to a similar message on a [Cisco ASA discussion thread](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/12391751/access-control-policy-block-response-page). I can also see that the source MAC of the 403 in your capture is indeed a Cisco device.
4. A RST packet is sent to both the client and server to forcibly close the connection. Notice how the source IP of each RST packet is the source IP of the other device. Something between those two devices has send a spoofed RST packet to both parties, claiming to be from the other.

Where about exactly are you performing your external testing from? Is it from a corporate network perhaps?

Comment: Wow, really nice analysis, I cannot thank you enough. Yes indeed I'm in a corporate network of some sort - spending involuntary time in a hospital :-( It seems, that the network here has my DynDNS provider blacklisted, which also explains why I could connect using only the IP address. What confused me very much is that it also didn't work from my phone over the mobile network - but that (I'm quite sure now) was an unrelated problem with my Apache config. Again, thank you so much for your time and effort.

Comment: No problem at all, I love digging into issues like these. I'm not sure if you are working at the hospital or in as a patient, but if it's the latter, I hope you are doing well and make a speedy recovery. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You say in your question that whilst running Apache you receive a "403 Forbidden" message.

That message is generated by Apache and so your request and response would appear to be being correctly processed by your network.

I would focus your further investigations on Apache config. How have you configured your server? If by IP address you need to make sure Apache knows it should respond both to local private IPs and also your public one. Can you post your httpd.conf and the files in your sites-enabled directory?

Comment: I'm not sure if Apache really generates the 403 message, because I simply don't see it in the TCP dump. My Apache conifg is rather complex, as I'm running many different services on it (nextcloud, munin, dokuwiki, SVN...). But as said, I turned Apache off and tried with a very simple (really just 3 lines) Python script, using the `SimpleHTTPServer` and `SocketServer` modules.